# How to display only results matching a certain condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I would appreciate your help very much as I’m still at beginner level in SQL. Thank you :)

I have tables representing counties, vendors and their respective sales of stationery products. I have to display only the counties where the sum of all sales exceeds 100 without counting vendor 2 (Randall). For these counties I need county name, vendor name and sales.

These are my tables (shortened):

`Counties`

| county_key | county_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Custer |
| 2 | Kimball |
| 3 | Douglas |
| 4 | Lancaster |

`Vendors`

| vendor_key | vendor_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Highsmith |
| 2 | Randall |
| 3 | Jackson |
| 4 | Herford |

`Sales`

| county_key | vendor_key | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 |
| 1 | 2 | 70 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 3 | 30 |
| 2 | 4 | 80 |
| 3 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 4 | 20 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 30 |
| 4 | 3 | 90 |
| 4 | 4 | 20 |

So in this case only counties 2 and 4 should be displayed (because county 1 sales are above 100 in total, but only with the contribution of vendor 2 Randall which should not be part; county 3 sales are below 100 anyway). Therefore, the result should be as follows:

| county_name | vendor_name | sales_wo_randall |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kimball | Jackson | 30 |
| Kimball | Herford | 80 |
| Lancaster | Highsmith | 30 |
| Lancaster | Jackson | 90 |
| Lancaster | Herford | 20 |

I worked out this code, but I didn't manage to include the sales > 100 condition:

```
WITH sales_wo_randall AS (
        SELECT county_key FROM Counties GROUP BY county_key HAVING SUM(sales) > 100
    )
SELECT co.county_name, ve.vendor_name, sa.sales
FROM Sales sa
JOIN Counties co
ON co.county_key = sa.county_key
JOIN Vendors ve
ON ve.vendor_key = sa.vendor_key
WHERE sa.date = '2022-01-01'
AND ve.vendor_name <> 'Randall'
GROUP BY co.county_name, ve.vendor_name, sa.sales
ORDER BY co.county_name
```

2nd try:
I tried to manage to include the sales > 100 condition, but then, I am not able to include my desired columns county_name and vendor_name as they would need to be included in `GROUP BY` clause which in turn unfortunately leads to getting just certain rows with sales > 100, not as a sum ... Here is the "correct" query but without my desired columns, as I stated:

```
SELECT
    sa.county_key,
    SUM(sa.sales)
FROM
    Sales sa
WHERE sa.date = '2022-01-01' AND sa.vendor_key <> '2'
GROUP BY
    sa.county_key
HAVING SUM(sa.sales) > 100
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anyone, please?  I did some SQL queries, but I‘m a beginner nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed it :)

Here is my answer if anybody has to struggle with the same problem:

```
WITH sales_wo_randall_greater_100 AS
(SELECT
    sa.county_key,
    SUM(sa.sales)
FROM
    Sales sa
WHERE sa.date = '2022-01-01' AND sa.vendor_key <> '2'
GROUP BY
    sa.county_key
HAVING SUM(sa.sales) > 100)

SELECT co.county_name, ve.vendor_name, sa.sales
FROM Sales sa
JOIN Counties co
ON co.county_key = sa.county_key
JOIN Vendors ve
ON ve.vendor_key = sa.vendor_key
WHERE sa.date = '2022-01-01'
AND ve.vendor_name <> 'Randall'
AND co.county_key IN (SELECT county_key FROM sales_wo_randall_greater_100)
GROUP BY co.county_name, ve.vendor_name, sa.sales
ORDER BY co.county_name
```

Answer (score 0):

in your WHERE clause cant you write 'sales > 100'?
or sales > '100'
That's what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because then I just receive rows with sales > 100 (which are none in this case). I need the counties having sales > 100 in total, without counting vendor Randall in this sales.

I tried another query where this works - using HAVING SUM(sa.sales) > 100, but there I just selected the county_key from the same table Sales and did not manage to select my desired other columns county_name and vendor_name from the other tables as then SQL say I have to put it in the GROUP BY too. But if I do that I again receive just certain rows having sales > 100 (see my second query above).